# Unable to retrieve contents of JSON post

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a script in Sheets that is supposed to flatten a JSON post but am having some difficulty getting around the format of the incoming JSON.

Below, I have an example POST which I am trying to parse. Underneath that is my doPost function, with some of the ways I have tried getting the content. doPost uses another function to actually parse the content, but I can't seem to get around what looks like an array formatted JSON?

Here is an example of the POST object:

```
[
  {
    "id": "xyz123",
    "payload": {
      "reference_id": "id_6",
      "unit_id": "000111222",
      "origin": {
        "name": "T-shirt Supply",
        "city": "Jiujiang",
        "state": "Jiangxi",
        "country": "China",
      },
      "destination": {
        "name": "Main Office",
        "city": "Surabaya",
        "state": "East Java",
        "country": "Indonesia",
      },
    },
    "status": "data_received",
    "created_at": "2020-01-29T07:41:33.918Z",
    "updated_at": "2020-01-29T07:41:33.918Z"
  }
]
```

I have tried in several ways to access the contents, such as payload.reference_id, but for some reason can't find my way into the curled brackets of the JSON object. Here are some of the ways I have tried:

```
function doPost(e){
  var data = e.postData.contents;
  // returns JSON formatted [{ "id": "xyz", "payload" : {"reference" : "1", "updated" : true}}]

  var data2 = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  // returns [object Object]
  
  var data3 = data[0];
  // returns [
  
  var data4 = ContentService.createTextOutput(e.postData.contents).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  // same result as 'data'
  
  return dataX;
}
```

I have also attempted various workarounds, such as parsing twice, stringify, and more. Any help is greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Can you check the request content type? It should be `postData.type`. Try setting it to `application/json` if you are sending the request (as opposed to a webhook)

Comment: Hi Abrar, thanks for your response. The postData.type is set to application/json

Comment: Can you try the following for data2: `Object.keys(data2)`? This should show all the keys on the objects and allow you understand the structure better.

Comment: Can you share more information on the script and how to reproduce it? Or if possible share a public copy of the project?

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to parse e.postData.contents, probably it is already an object, not string.

Or if it is string and there is only one element, you can try this:

```js
var data2 = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents.slice(1,-1));
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to output the object of the 1st element in an array which is your sample value from `doPost`.

If my understanding is correct, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```
function doPost(e){
  var data2 = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(data2[0])).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

- In this modification, it supposes that `e.postData.contents` is your sample value. Please be careful about this.
- When the above-modified script is used, the 1st element of the array is returned.

#### Note:

- When you modified the Google Apps Script, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.
- You can see the detail of this in the report of "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

#### Reference:

- [createTextOutput()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/content/content-service?hl=ja#createTextOutput())